# How to select particular note in sql on the basis of case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]I am trying to write a case query which have three conditions and on the basis of that condition a particular note  action will be selected i am writing the query but it is not giving output

```
select lportal.msh_InternalSubmission.name
    , lportal.msh_InternalSubmission.email
    , CU.name 
    , DATE_FORMAT(CD.dateAdded,'%Y-%m-%d')
    , CD.userID 
    , jNote.jobOrderID 
from candidate CD 
    , db_candidatenote Note 
    , corporateuser CU 
    , db_jobordernote jNote 
    , lportal.msh_InternalSubmission 
where CD.userID = Note.candidateID 
    and jNote.noteID = Note.noteID 
    and lportal.msh_InternalSubmission.candidateId = CD.userID 
    and Note.commentingPersonID = CU.userID 
    and lportal.msh_InternalSubmission.submitted like 'NO' 
    and ( 
            case when Note.action = 'Qualification' or  Note.action = 'Engaged' 
            then Note.action = 'Qualification' 
            when Note.action ='Qualification' else Note.action ='Engaged' end
        ) 
    and jNote.jobOrderID =1844;
```

How to solve this

Comment: Note.action ='Qualification' or  Note.action ='Engaged' then Note.action ='Qualification' - you cannot modify a field's value in a select query. Can you pls be more specific what you want to achieve?

Comment: You need to fix first your `CASE WHEN` condition, it looks wrong.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. What shall happen exactly when a record's Note.action = 'Engaged'?

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement...

Comment: I mean when both note equals qualification and engaged then Note.action ="qualification" will be selected

Comment: No. You are looking at a note record. It has a field `action`. This field can contain *either* 'qualification' *or* 'engaged', not both at the same time. So you are talking of *different* records. But which? Are you talking about all candidate notes with job order ID 1844 per submission? Or all candidate notes per submission no matter what job order ID? Or what else? Provide sample data and desired results.